# Incremenent NSnumber every 5 seconds - Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsnumber

I am trying to increment a `NSNumber` every 5 seconds by 1 in Cocos2d but for some reason it isn't working (probably obvious mistake). I am using the update method but I think this may be the wrong place. Currently it is only adding +1 once. I need it to do this every 5 seconds constantly:

```
-(void) update: (CCTime) delta
{
    // Save a string:
    NSNumber *anInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:500];

    NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[anInt intValue] + 1];

    NSLog(@"Update Number%@",bNumber);   

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSNumber` instead of `int`?

Comment: you create a new number with the same value (500) every update, then you increment it, then the number goes out of scope and deallocates

Comment: Why do you expect to see a value other than 501 over and over?

Comment: @trojanfoe I wasn't sure to use NSnumber or int when I started.

Comment: There's an important distinction between the two and you need to learn what it is ASAP.

Comment: @trojanfoe Its for scoring. I did read up on them but maybe I misunderstood. Opps.

Comment: so what do I do for my answer?

Comment: Make a property that is of type `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to run something every 5 seconds would be to:

Create a property storing your number and a timer:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int bNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* timer;
```

Then initialize the number to 500 (I assume based on your example you want it to start at 500) and create the timer:

```
- (instanceType)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.bNumber = 500;

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(incrementScore:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

Then create a method that does the increment:

```
- (void)incrementScore:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.bNumber++;
    NSLog(@"Number = %d", self.bNumber);
}
```

Don't forget to invalidate the timer when you are done:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    // If not using arc don't forget super dealloc
    [super dealloc];

    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
```

That is one way. If you want to use the update method in cocos2d then you need to be keeping track of the accumulated delta. Once that value has reached or exceeded the total number of milliseconds in 5 seconds, then you add 1 to the number. Delta is the number of milliseconds that have passed since the last update. So for example the properties will be:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int bNumber;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CCTime totalDelta;
```

Then in update you would do the following (there are 1000 milliseconds in a second):

```
- (void)update:(CCTime)delta
{
    const CCTime FiveSeconds = 5000.0f;
    self.totalDelta += delta;

    if (self.totalDelta >= FiveSeconds)
    {
        self.totalDelta = 0;
        self.bNumber++;

        NSLog(@"Number = %d", self.bNumber);
    }
}
```

I hope this helped. What you are trying to do is pretty simply so I recommend brushing up on Obj-C programming before jumping into making games.

Comment: Thanks. I knew how to do it with NStimer already but it was with the update method in Cocos2d that I was struggling with. I read that NStimer was best avoided in preference to cocos2d hence my question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think method `[self schedule:@selector(methodName) interval:intervalValue];` is your choice.

Code sample:

```

```
static CGFloat playTime = 0.0;
@implementation GameScene {

}

-(void)onEnter
{
    CCLOG(@"on enter");
    [self schedule:@selector(runTimer) interval:5.0];
    [super onEnter];
}

-(void) runTimer {
    playTime += 1;
}
```

```