# How do I go about adding a score that counts up every second to my iOS game using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to display a score at near the top of the scene. Scoring is dependent on the amount of seconds you have lasted and whenever I have tried to implement using NSTimer, the number remains at 0. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend posting your current code. In its current state, there's no way anyone could know the answer to this question.

Comment: change to 1 second and use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024213/incremenent-nsnumber-every-5-seconds-cocos2d

Comment: @Ryan Allen In Spritekit you should not use NSTimer for time related actions because NSTimer don't respect nodes, scene's or views paused state. So you get the point...The good way would be like Ben pointed in his answer, or using the update: method and it's currentTime passed parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need an `NSTimer`. Since you are using SpriteKit, you can use `SKAction` for this. Here's an example:

```
let increaseScoreAction = SKAction.runBlock { score++ }
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
let groupAction = SKAction.group([increaseScoreAction, waitAction])
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(groupAction)

runAction(repeatAction)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, very simplistically this is what I tried and it works fine. I am storing the timer as an instance variable to invalidate it later if necessary.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var score: Int = 0
    var timer: NSTimer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("incrementTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)        
    }

    func incrementTimer() {
        score++
        println(score)
    }
}
```